# Is any superset of an undecidable set is uncountable?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-languages

This statement really made me confused, Is any superset of an undecidable set is uncountable?

Answer (score 3):

All sets of words over a finite alphabet are countable. Stated differently, no set of words over a finite alphabet is uncountable.